# Problema al crear socket en android al servidor en el pc

Tags: java, android, socket, excepciones

Estoy haciendo un chat para un proyecto en el grado que curso, tengo ya cliente y servidor que funcionan en java en el pc.

Ahora quería hacer un cliente en versión móvil. La cuestión es que estoy estancado en la creación del `socket`, ya que me tira por una excepción genérica y no consigo hacerlo funcionar. Os pego el código del cliente, a ver si me podéis echar una mano:

```java
public class chat extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket socket;
    private TextView tvChat;
    private EditText etMensaje;
    private String mensaje;
    private int puerto;
    private InetAddress ip;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        tvChat =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvChat);
        tvChat.setText("");
        etMensaje = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMensaje);
            tvChat.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        String temp;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            temp = (String)extras.get("IP");
            try {
                ip=InetAddress.getByName(temp);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tvChat.append(ip.toString());
            p=Integer.parseInt((String)extras.get("Puerto"));
            tvChat.append(String.valueOf(p));
        }
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try{
            Process mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 192.168.1.137");
            int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
            if (mExitValue == 0){
                tvChat.append("Ha salido bien");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip,p);
        } catch (UnknownHostException uhe){
            Toast.makeText(this, "La ip no apunta a ningun servidor disponible. " + uhe.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException ioe){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error de entrada y salida. "+ ioe.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error genérico. "+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

***Lo curioso es que ejecutándolo en el móvil, el ping me lo hace, pero no realiza la conexión...***

Comment: Puedes añadir la excepción genérica por favor.

Answer (score 1):

No puede establecer la conexión desde el **hilo principal**, para evitar que se congele la UI, tienes que lanzar la conexión desde un hilo secundario.

Una tarea asincrónica (Asyncasck) se define por un cálculo que se ejecuta en un hilo secundario y cuyo resultado queremos que se publique en el hilo del interfaz de usuario.

Agregue permiso en su Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Cree una clase extendiendo la clase AsyncTask:

```
private class Conectar extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

           SERVER_IP = params[0];
           SERVER_PORT = params[1];
           TIME_OUT = params[2];


            try {
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, Integer.valueOf(SERVER_PORT)), Integer.valueOf(TIME_OUT));
                Log.v(TAG,"Socket conectado");

                return true;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Socket NO conectado");
                return false;
            }

        }


    }
```

Establezca un procedimiento para llamar a dicha clase.

```
private Conectar mCon = null;

private boolean setConectar(String IP, String Puerto, String TimeOut){

        mCon = new Conectar();
        mCon.execute(IP,Puerto,TimeOut);//En milisegundos

        try {

            if(mCon.get(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

En la parte de su código llame a setCoenctar().

```
if(setConectar("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","3333","5000")){
   //Si esta conectado haga algo
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, pero hay algo que no se hacer. Para crear la conexión, tengo que pasarle dos parametros, ip y puerto, que tengo en la activity chat, como le paso esos parametros al Asynctask?

Comment: Le agregue también el timeout como parámetro.

Comment: Vale, ya esta funcionando! Muchisimas gracias, la verdad es que sin tu ayuda no lo habría podido hacer! :)